# Include template for Springboot/Thymeleaf application

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, templating

**Index Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TmtApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**MVC Config:**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/request").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/requests").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/team").setViewName("index");
    }

}
```

In PHP, we have a simple include function in the part of the template we want to swap out when we click on a new link:

```
<a href="index.php?action=notifications">notifications</a>

    if (!empty($_GET['action'])) { 
    $action = $_GET['action']; 
    $action = basename($action); 
    if (file_exists("templates/$action.htm") 
        $action = "index"; 
    include("templates/$action.htm"); 
} else { 
    include("templates/index.htm"); 
}
```

**On my index.html:**

```
<body>

<div class="container" style="width: 100% !important;">

    <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></div>

    // Include dynamic content here depending on which menu item was clicked
    <div th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${template}} :: ${template}"></div>

    <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>

</div>

</body>
```

What's the equivalent for Springboot/Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html

You have to put the objects you can use in expressions into the (Spring) model with your controller. My guess is that it should work, wenn you do somthing like

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
String index(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("template", "my-template")
    return "index";
}
```

it should work

Comment: What does the ''my-template" parameter you provided do?

Comment: This value should be inserted into 

<div th:replace="@{'fragments/' + ${template}} :: ${template}"></div>

Comment: I see what you mean but this value should always be different depending on which url the user has clicked. One of my links looks like this for example ``<a href="#" th:href="@{/request}">Make a Request</a>``. It should load index.html and replace the content div with the request.html fragment.

Comment: Yes but you can control this in your Controller with e.g. model.addAttribute("template", determineTheNameOfTheTemplate(request))

Comment: Are you saying I should pass a new function that checks the name of the "template" parameter that assigns a new view based on that?

Comment: No I am saying that you can set the variable "template" within the ModelMap to whatever value you like depending on whatever you like. You can use information from the request or from the session or the application